# Outside class or nested class?

Tags: c#, class-design

I have a class as following:

```
public class A
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }
    public string P2 { get; set; }

    public B b = new B();

    public A()
    {
        b.B1 = ...
        b.B2 = ...
    }
}
```

Where class B is outside (not nested) class:

```
public class B
{
    public string B1 { get; set; }
    public string B2 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string B20 { get; set; }
}
```

I'm wondering if this is correct design because class B contains only data members that originally was in class A, but I need to refactor it because they logically belong to separate entity. They are now outside class A in class B. Should I put class B inside class A (to be nested) and if so, how does it look like and how to initialize members of class B in constructor of class A in that case?

Comment: Does anyone else except for `A` that uses `B`?

Comment: I edited your title because the concensus is that [tags shouldn't be used in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: @ Marius Bancila: Yes.

Comment: The instance b, should that be visible outside of A? 
Because if not I'd think your implementation of B within A should have b be private and should be initialized within A's constructur. If b should be visible outside A, you'd should send the instance b as a parameter to the constructor of A.

Comment: The important point about nested classes is that you are declaring types, not member fields. It happens to be possible to enclose one type declaration in another, but they do not merge into the same type. http://www.dotnetperls.com/nested-class